# Maintain an auto-cleanable list of threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I maintain a `threads` list, and I want to **auto-remove threads from the list when they are finished**.

I found this method:

```
import threading, time

def f(seconds, info):
    print('starting', seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print('finished', seconds)
    threads.remove(info['thread'])

def newaction(seconds):
    info = {}
    thread = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(seconds, info))
    info['thread'] = thread
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

threads = []
newaction(1)
newaction(2)
for _ in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(threads)
```

It works:

```
starting 1
starting 2
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 1612)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 1612)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 1612)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
finished 1
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 712)>]
finished 2
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

But the fact of having to pass a dict `info` is a bit a hack. I used it because obviously I can't pass `thread` in `args`...

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(seconds, thread))  
#                                                     ^ not created yet!
```

...when the `Thread` object is not created yet!

**Is there a more natural way in Python to maintain an auto-cleanable list of threads?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `current_thread()` function.

```
import threading, time

def f(seconds):
    print('starting', seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print('finished', seconds)
    threads.remove(threading.current_thread())

def newaction(seconds):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(seconds,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

threads = []
newaction(1)
newaction(2)
for _ in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print(threads)
```

Output:

```
starting 1
starting 2
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 4588)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 4588)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
[<Thread(Thread-1, started 4588)>, <Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
finished 1
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
[<Thread(Thread-2, started 4388)>]
finished 2
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Thank you @igrinis! `current_thread` is helpful indeed. I edited your answer to remove the dict `info`, no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing Thread results in a solution with a natural syntax and a secure place to keep the list of threads. You also don't have to include an instruction to remove the thread at the end of every function you want to run in another thread. Simply use the subclass.

```
import threading, time

class AutoRemovingThread(threading.Thread):
  threads = []
  def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.threads.append(self)
    self.func = func
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
  def run(self):
    self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    self.threads.remove(self)

def f(seconds):
  print('starting', seconds)
  time.sleep(seconds)
  print('finished', seconds)

def newaction(seconds):
  AutoRemovingThread(f, seconds).start()

newaction(1)
newaction(2)
for _ in range(10):
  time.sleep(0.3)
  print(AutoRemovingThread.threads)
```

Outputs:

```
starting 1
starting 2
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-1, started 8436)>, <AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-1, started 8436)>, <AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-1, started 8436)>, <AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
finished 1
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
[<AutoRemovingThread(Thread-2, started 1072)>]
finished 2
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

`python-3.8`

Comment: Nice idea! I'm not sure it's a good idea in general to keep a list as class attribute (not instance attribute but class) like that: `class AutoRemovingThread(threading.Thread):
  threads = []`? It's unusual to see this, but it could work. What could be the drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import threading

def get_status_of_threads():
    current_threads = threading.enumerate()

    thread_data = []

    for item in current_threads:
        try:
            print(str(item.target))
        except AttributeError:
            print("item", str(item))
        thread_data.append({"thread_name": item.getName(), "status": int(item.is_alive()), "id": item.ident})
    return thread_data
```

The above code is tested in Python2.7, you can use this in a separate thread if you want to continuously monitor the threads, or you can expose this as an API, so you can check whenever you want. That will also help in less wastage of resources for the same.

For API, you can use `json2html.convert({"thread_data":thread_data})` function to display it in a more aesthetic way in a tabular form.

Comment: This might work, but it would expose all the threads of my process. I would prefer to classify them, and have a list that monitors only the threads created with `newaction(...)` in my example.

Comment: For this, you can name the threads in the `newaction` method in a pattern and add a check in the `get_status_of_threads` method in my answer based on that pattern.